# Simply recording sound and modifying it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm want to make a test app to record some sound and then modify the pitch.

Anybody able to gimme some advice what technologies on the iphone are the best (and simplest) to record some sound, and then after the recording I want to be able to pitch shift the sound to make it sound deeper. It doesn't need to be fast. The processing will not be done in realtime.

Can iphone record sound and save to WAV format?

I've never worked with sounds before, so this is all very new to me.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: To be fair, there is nothing simple about recording audio and modifying the source's pitch. Have you taken the time to look into any of Apple's media frameworks for iOS? Do you have questions about any framework in particular?

Comment: No specific frameworks. Was just looking for some advice. I've read a lot of other threads here on Stackoverflow. But there is no sure way to do it. I think the way i can handle it is to record the sound with AVAudiorecorder and then play it using OpenAL since it has pitch settings. Though the results... who knows. May work well or be horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to read the [Core Audio guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html). This framework is really powerful and includes the `AUPitch` audio unit (I don’t know if this is available on iOS though) which does exactly what you want. But Core Audio is rather complex, so I can’t explain it all here. Read the guide, look at the sample code and try it yourself. If you have any concrete questions then they most likely will get answered quicker.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitParametersReference/Reference/reference.html "These parameters are not used in iOS."